# The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Future'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method

Tags: flutter, dart

The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'.dartundefined_method

this is the error i face  please hep...
snippet

```
final DataBaseHelper dbhelper=DataBaseHelper();
  late Future< List<Note>> allnotes=dbhelper.getNote();
```

later i used `allnotes.map()` to generate a listview

Comment: can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i was unable to add code snippet caz body was limited to 30 characters i

Comment: for functions returning type  Future, you need to "await" its callback if you want to receive data from it. - It will be better if you could add the code snippet to the question.

Comment: you can include description and code snippet [%]

Answer (score 0):

`allnotes` is a future list, you can await to fetch the list from it and then perform `.map`.

```dart
myMethod() async{
 final result  =  await allnotes();

 ///now you can use `.map` on `result`
 result.map(...
```

Also you may use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for this.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: allnotes,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {

  if(snapshot.hasData){
    final data  = snapshot.data?? [];
      /// data.map
    return 
  }
  .....
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
},)
```